# How long does my code take to run?

Tags: c#, benchmarking, performance

How can I find out how much time my C# code takes to run?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out the [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

// your code here

sw.Stop();
TimeSpan elapsedTime = sw.Elapsed;
```

Answer (score 14):

The [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class offers high-precision timing in .NET. It is capable of measuring time with sensitivity of around 100s of nanoseconds (fractions of milliseconds). To get the exact resolution, read the value of [`Stopwatch.Frequency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency.aspx).

```
var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
// Run code here.
var elapsed = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds.
```

Also, be sure to *run your code repeatedly* (as many times as is feasible) to get a better average time, as well as to reduce the effects of fluctuations in CPU load.

Answer (score 8):

As others have said, the [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class is good for the simple timing side of things. Other bits to bear in mind though:

- Your code may generate objects which will need to be garbage collected after you've stopped the stopwatch
- Conversely your timing may include *other* objects being garbage collected even if they have nothing to do with your code
- If you start timing before you run your method for the first time, it will include JIT time
- If you take a very short time, that leads to very unpredictable results - for benchmarking I tend to prefer running code for many seconds, to account for the app being interrupted by other processes etc.

If you're interested in benchmarking, I have the [MiniBench](http://code.google.com/p/minibench/) project which I must get round to working on again at some point - it's not quite where I want it to end up, but it's a start. I talk more about what I want to achieve with it in [this blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/02/benchmarking-designing-an-api-with-unusual-goals.aspx).

Comment: Personal thanks for MiniBench, Jon - it has become invaluable tool to me.

Comment: @C Rogers: You've probably used it more than I have then! I really will get back to it some time... writing has rather taken over for the moment though :(

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a profiling tool such as [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) to test the speed of your application and find slow code.  This will allow you to do a line-by-line test of execution times.

Answer (score 0):

If you want simple, just put an N-iteration loop around it and use StopWatch (or just a wristwatch) and divide by N. For example, if you want microseconds, let N = 1000000. If you're worried about the overhead of the loop, just unroll it by a factor of 10.